# Pagination can not link to page 2 wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi all I have problame with pagination with link to page 2 I installed plugin Wp-pagnavi ,When I click link to page 2 its dont show the content page 2,it still stay at page 1, How can I fix this.

you can see it at 
http://westecmedia.com/?page_id=758

and this is my code blog post page:

```
<?php
/*
 *  Template Name: Page - Events Page
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content-events">
    <div id="head-event"><h3>EVENTS</h3></div>
    <div id="main-event">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>

    <?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div id="part-event">
    <div id="entry-thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    </div>
    <div id="event-dess">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p>
            <?php 
            $content = get_the_content();
            $content = strip_tags($content);
            echo substr($content, 0, 300);
            ?>
        </p>
        <div id="read-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
    </div>

</div>
        <div id="line-bottom"></div>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
        <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Help me please ?

Comment: Did you try by changing permalink structure to post name?

Comment: The first I ahve problame with page 2 not found I try to change it to defalt permalink, after I chang it to defalt ,when I click link to page 2 its still stay at page 1, it same page 1

Comment: hi brother can see at http://westecmedia.com/?page_id=758

Comment: can you help me brother ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put all this in a loop and set `wp_reset_query();` and also have to use `paged` option post per page in `query_post` .
Try this

```
<?php
/*
 *  Template Name: Page - Events Page
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content-events">
    <div id="head-event"><h3>EVENTS</h3></div>
    <div id="main-event">

                <?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged,category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div id="part-event">
                            <div id="entry-thumbnail">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                            </div>
                            <div id="event-dess">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                <p>
                                    <?php 
                                    $content = get_the_content();
                                    $content = strip_tags($content);
                                    echo substr($content, 0, 300);
                                    ?>
                                </p>
                                <div id="read-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="line-bottom"></div>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/ visit here. I think here some instruction will help u.

Comment: This project I contnue from other web developer ,

Comment: Hi brother very Thz q for ur help full, but now I find the correct code ,u can see my answer up,

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'cat' => '5',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
);
query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 /* Do whatever you want to do for every page... */
endwhile;
wp_pagenavi();
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data
?>
```

Comment: Yeah u missed paged query in ur submitted question. Good job. I also suggested u to put that paged query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194434/why-my-new-users-wordpress-dont-have-post