# Why my new users wordpress dont have Post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to create a new user to post events, but my new user, called *admin*, doesn't have the ability to post. I tried changing his role to `Editor`, `Subscriber`, `Author`, and `Contribute`, but I still cannot post with *admin*.

Currently only the Administrator can post, how can I give *admin* the rights to do so as well?

[image]

Comment: Are u telling that if without administrator any one login "they can't see post option" in admin panel.

Comment: Yes brother, I want have Posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your new user role has some limitations.
To change the settings of a user role you can use the 
**[user role editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)** plugin.
To change the admin menu you can use the **[adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/)** plugin.

Follow the instructions of these plugins to customize your new user roles and their access capabilities.

Comment: Ok I will try ur plugin brother

Comment: Happy to help u too. Carry on and enjoy coding,

Comment: Yes Very thz again brother :D